# Insert into table with multiple select including select distinct from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables (simplified) below:

Table1

```
| productname | certno | expdate    | company 
+-------------+--------+------------+---------
| abc         | 123    | 2020-01-01 | ABC 
| def         | 123    | 2020-01-01 | ABC 
| qwe         | 456    | 2020-01-02 | ABC 
| asd         | 999    | 2020-02-02 | DEF 
| ..          | ..     | ..         | ..
```

Table2

```
| companyid | company 
+-----------+---------
|    1      | ABC           
|    2      | DEF           
|    ..     | ..
```

And I need to insert data from these 2 tables into another table for distinct `certno`, Table3 should be like this:

```
| certid | companyid | certno | expdate    | createddate | is_null 
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+---------
|  1     |    1      | 123    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-09-12  | 1
|  2     |    1      | 456    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-09-12  | 1
|  3     |    2      | 999    | 2020-02-02 | 2020-09-12  | 1
|  ..    |    ..     | ..     | ..         | ..          | ..
```

I'm currently using this query, I need to create a script so that next batch of update is just in one query.

```sql
insert into Table3 (certno, expdate, is_null)
select distinct certno, expdate
from Table1
where company like '%ABC%';

--then I will update Table3 to complete it

update Table3
set companyid = '1',
createddate = getdate(),
is_null = '1'
where is_null is null;     --edited**

--then repeat the above until I have all companies registered as companyid in Table3
```

But this will be a hassle when it involved more companies and lots of data and I was thinking of using multiple select including select distinct but I'm stuck right here:

```sql
insert into Table3 (companyid, certno, expdate, createddate)
select
     (select companyid from Table2
      where company in (select company from Table1)
     ),
     (select distinct certno),
     expdate,
     getdate()
from Table1;
```

I did not run the script to see whether it works or not because I don't want to mess up the Table3 data and I feel that the script is not going to work.

Is there any way to just run the query in one script?

Comment: Why not `INSERT... SELECT DISTINCT certno, expdate, company, GETDATE() FROM Table1`? `Table2` doesn't look like it's needed here at all.

Comment: It's the database architecture from previous dev, and they still want these tables with this format, yeah it looks redundant but I'm new here cannot change the way they systemized this ^^;

Comment: oh sorry, I have somehow did a mistake in the ask content, I edited it just now. Table3 still needs the `companyid` from Table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `insert . . . select` with `join`:

```
insert into Table3 (companyid, certno, expdate, createddate, is_null)
    select distinct t2.companyid, t1.certno, t1.expdate, getdate(), 1
    from Table1 t1 join
         Table2 t2
         on t1.company = t2.company
    where t1.company like '%ABC%';
```

You can remove the `where` clause to insert all companies in one `insert`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. However, I received error message "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'companyid' "
I only want distinct `certno` and from what I can understand, your suggestion was joining the table and getting distinct `companyid` from Table1, is it?

Comment: @Nadhirah21 . . . The typo is fixed.  That should clearly be `t2.companyid`.

Comment: Eventually I just learned that the sequence/order for the `insert into` does not matter for sql server. So I rearrange your suggestion
`insert into Table3 (certno, companyid, expdate, createddate, is_null)
   select distinct t1.certno, t2.companyid, t1.expdate, getdate(), 1 ...`
and got it solved! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to expand the columns in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table3 (certno, expdate, companyid, createdate)
SELECT DISTINCT
       certno,
       expdate,
       company,
GETDATE()
FROM dbo.Table1;
```